# How to change android app widget size at runtime?

Tags: java, android, resize, android-appwidget

I know that one cannot change the size of an app widget. But what to do if I need to? I know that there can be several receivers in AndroidManifest.xml, each with its own provider_info.xml, but users can switch between them only while adding widget on the homescreen. Is there any way to switch between different app widget providers at runtime?

Comment: I've read that beginning from the Honeycomb you can resize your App Widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read that beginning from the Honeycomb 3.1 you can resize your App Widgets. You should specify minResizeWidth and minResizeHeight in your appwidget_info.xml file and use layouts for widget that can be resized. More about this you can find [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html).

Comment: Yes, but I need to support at least Android 2.x.

Comment: Then, actually I do not know how to solve this problem. I can propose to use different provider_info files for different screen size but I do not think that this is exactly what you want.

Comment: Look at this screenshot: [link](https://lh3.ggpht.com/6H_w8zBVlthdBI-FgQtXCXGEh5Z5RgB_gK3E45gMJGna3_jvYFqmMojquNIuR6tkRD2Q). That widget shows a list of currencies ans stocks quotes. Users can select which currencies and quotes to show. So one need to change the size of a widget to fit all selected elements.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to include in the layout one textbox which fills the whole parent element. And then just add new lines to it. But I have not ever tried this approach.

Comment: The widgets in that screenshot are using different layouts. It's not possible to do what you're asking. You need to create your widgets in different sizes.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any way to switch between different app widget providers at runtime?

No, not as far as I'm aware. I believe this is the reason why some applications include widgets in various different sizes.

It's also not possible for the user to change the size of widgets, if you need to support Android 2.0+.

**Edit:** As of Android 4.1, it is actually possible to have different layouts for resizable widgets. The layouts change according to the size of the widget.

Comment: Can you expand on this: "The layouts change according to the size of the widget". Cannot find it in official documentation

Comment: I'd be interested in an example of that as well :)